# Designing my own icon for use in OpenLayers implementation

Tags: openlayers, markers

I have been searching for a simple way to create an icon to add to my OpenLayers implementation.

Currently I have an implementation I found in the documentation which utilizes a png file, but I was wondering if it isn't possible to style a regular circle and give it a color of my own desire?

I my current implementation I have is:

```
//setting location of marker
var location = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([longitude, latitude]))
});

//styling marker
location.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon({
        color: '##4271AE',
        crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
        src: 'https://openlayers.org/en/v4.2.0/examples/data/dot.png'
    })
});
```

I am having a lot of markers close to each other and by using the code above my markers appear as follows:

[image: map example]

I guess I could just scale them using

```
new ol.style.Icon({
    color: '#4271AE',
    crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
    src: 'https://openlayers.org/en/v4.2.0/examples/data/dot.png',
    scale: 0.25
})
```

But basically what my problem is, is the outline (stroke) on the circle. I guess I could style my own white circle, in a regular drawing program and use that, but I find that quite cumbersome considering I am just wanting to create a colored circle. I would assume this was implemented in OpenLayers, but I can't find any documentation supporting this.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to piece together a lot of code I found different places which resolved in a fix for my problem.

I have a js function called setStyle in which I added the Icon from my question.

I changed the function by styling and adding a "circle":

```
var fill = new ol.style.Fill({
    color: 'rgba(255,255,255,1)'
});

var circle = new ol.style.Circle({
    radius: 1,
    fill: fill
});

location.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
    image: circle
}));
```

I didn't need a stroke for my circle, but if you do you can add that by using:

```
var stroke = new ol.style.Stroke({
    color: 'rgba(255,0,0,0)',
    width: 0
});

var circle = new ol.style.Circle({
    radius: 1,
    fill: fill,
    stroke: stroke
});
```